# Set Row Names in JQGrid

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

Currently working in MVC 3 in Visual Studio 2012, and looking to dynamically fill a jqGrid with data from a Database.

Hypothetically speaking, I would like to dynamically name the "row headers" on the far left where they are ordered numerically (ie- 1, 2, 3,..., 10). Ordering shouldn't matter in regards to the rows, while the column headers would be some fixed "mm-yyyy" format.

I'm not sure if this is entirely possible, but if anyone could give me some pointers I'd much appreciate it.

[Hypothetical Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBX2A.png)

Comment: I don't quite understand what you meant by "dynamically name the row headers". The hypothetical image shows a normal numerical row header.. Confused man is confused.

Comment: So basically, you'd give the row headers custom names.

The example image has row headers 1, 2, 3 etc. Instead those would be replaced with strings like "alpha", "beta", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ach, nevermind.

I figured I could just input a read-only column to do the same thing.

Thanks.